# Powerpivot dax RANKX using two separate tables

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have two tables I am bringing into powerpivot via ODBC and powerquery and ranking using the below. In the case of a tiebreak I'm using RAND () and then regenerating.

The problem I am having is I now have a second table that I need to also incorporate into my RANK and unsure how to do a CROSSJOIN or create a measure that will evaluate both tables in my data model. Currently ive done as a calculated column.

Can anyone help?

```
=
RANKX (
    FILTER ( 'Table1', [Reference_ID] = EARLIER ( 'Table1'[Reference_ID] ) ),
    'Table1'[Date], , DESC, DENSE
)
```

Table 1

```
Partner Reference ID    Date
Bank of America R1290   1/1/2018
Bank of America R1291   1/2/2018
Bank of America R1291   1/3/2018
```

Table 2

```
Partner Reference ID    Date
Bank of America R1290   1/2/2018
Bank of America R1291   1/5/2018
Bank of America R1291   1/6/2018
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to `CROSSJOIN`; you want to `UNION`.

```
Rank =
VAR TableUnion =
    UNION (
        SELECTCOLUMNS ( Table1, "RefID", Table1[Reference_ID], "Date", Table1[Date] ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS ( Table2, "RefID", Table2[Reference_ID], "Date", Table2[Date] )
    )
RETURN
    RANKX ( FILTER ( TableUnion, [RefID] = [Reference_ID] ), [Date], , DESC, DENSE )
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I still seem to be getting an error in the measure. Could it be because two reference ID's have the same date?

Comment: If you're getting an error, it would be useful to know what the error message says.